# Lightning Inheritance : overridden parent component methods?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

As I am reading this document on Aura inheritance:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_whats_inherited.htm

Specifically around parent helper methods which can be overridden in child component. But no where in the documentation it mentions how do the actual implementation gets called.

Ex : cmp B extends cmp A. 
B overrides a method M present in A's helper.

How do I make some A's method call the B's version of M, instead of calling A's version.

Reading some articles its suggested to use : component.getConcreteComponent().getDef().getHelper().

Trying to find out :
Is this acceptable way to call the overridden methods from Parent ?

Answer (score 1):

The method you found is correct ( [source1](http://peterknolle.com/lightning-component-inheritance/), [source2](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/03/salesforce-lightning-components-by-example-component-extension.html) )

I don't find an alternative. Although if you are going to have multiple overridden methods on multiple classes, I suggest using an interface instead

Comment: Thanks for the links, those were the only 2 links I was able to find on this topic. Hence was wondering if thats the correct way of doing it. Maybe thats what it is then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is no longer possible when LockerService is activated (optional in Summer '16 and enforced in Winter '17).
Further discussions see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118270/lightning-lockerservice-and-component-inheritance)