# The passed helper to a custom renderer doesn't respect component inheritance

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, locker-service

I have an abstract extensible Lightning component called `Base` and a component that implements it that is called `Child`.

In the `Base` component, I have a custom renderer that implements the `rerender` method. The method uses the provided `helper` and calls some methods on it.

Depending on whether we are in the `Base` or `Child` method, the renderer has to do something different. Before Locker Service, we were able to use `cmp.getConcreteComponent().helper`, but now, I can't find any other options.

I think it's [pretty much this issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118270/lightning-lockerservice-and-component-inheritance), but I can't use the solution, I want to execute actual *code* and I don't feel that the solution there is OK.

Comment: Won't calling an aura:method of the concrete component which in turn calls the helper work out?

Comment: How do I access the concrete component? `getConcreteComponent()` isn't accessible when Locker Service is activated.

Comment: You can use my solution to access child helper with method callconcretecmphelper http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118270/lightning-lockerservice-and-component-inheritance

Comment: @Marc-AntoineVeilleux `getConcreteComponent()` is exposed on Components you have access to (`SecureComponent`) when Locker is activated. You just can't directly access the helper. @Praveen made a good suggestion to try going through an `aura:method`. If you don't see `getConcreteComponent` on your component then you're probably dealing with a `SecureComponentRef`, which means you don't have access to that particular component. What is output when you toString the component?

Comment: I was wrong, it's `getDef()` or `.helper` that isn't exposed. I did check the `callconcretecmphelper` solution, it's actually in my question. Using this method, it will ignore any linter (because method are strings), we need to serialize object through attributes for return values (so no complex object or function can be returned) and it feels and is an hack.


I've check the aura framework code, and there are calls to `getDef().getHelper()` (or equivalent) everywhere! To me, this is a design flaw pure and simple. @TrevorBliss, where is the best way to give feedback about design issues?

Comment: Not being able to directly access the helper was a conscious design decision the framework team made and you need to go through a more "public API" approach. This would include aura:method, events, or a library. Let me get back to you on the best way to give feedback.

Comment: @TrevorBliss Any update on the recommend practice?

Comment: @Praveen The best answer I could get would be to post an Issue on the open-source Aura repo for things regarding specific framework APIs like this. Unfortunately, whether your Issue gets any attention is a bit hit or miss currently... https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue