# Lightning Component Polymorphism is not working:

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, inheritance, polymorphism, polymorphic

I am trying to use [Bob Buzzard approach](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2016/03/lightning-components-it-inheritance-jim.html) to get Lightning Component Polymorphism working, so I have method

```
myAction: function(component) {
    component.getConcreteComponent().getDef().getHelper().callHelperMethod();
}
```

however, I receive an error

> TypeError: Action failed:
>   c:MyComponent$controller$myAction
>   [component.getConcreteComponent(...).getDef is not a function]
>   Callback failed:
>   apex://c:MyComponentController/ACTION$myAction

Why `getDef` is no longer available in Lightning? I can see that it is still present [in Aura framework code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getHelper)

Comment: You can access the aura doc using: `https://your-org.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app#reference?topic=api:Component`. There is no `getDef()` method. Neither `getHelper()` method.

Comment: Yeah, `getDef()` was never a documented method. However, due to Bob Buzzard article it used to be accessible

Comment: I describe a solution using aura:method there : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118270/lightning-lockerservice-and-component-inheritance/133702

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
if ( !component.isConcrete() ) return;
```

code in the parent component helper.

So my parent component looks like this

```
<aura:component extensible="true">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="importantAttribute" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.importantAttribute}" action="{!c.myAction}"/>
</aura:component>
```

my parent component controller

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        // do a lot of stuff and set importantAttribute
    },

    myAction: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.callImportantMethod(component);
    }
})
```

my parent component helper

```
({
    callImportantMethod: function(component) {
        if ( !component.isConcrete() ) return;
        // Execute Important logic in parent
    }, //other important methods
})
```

So my child component looks like this

```
<aura:component extends="c:ParentComponent">
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.importantAttribute}" action="{!c.myAction}"/>
</aura:component>
```

my child component controller

```
({
    myAction: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.callImportantMethod(component);
    }
})
```

my child component helper

```
({
    callImportantMethod: function(component) {
        // Execute DIFFERENT Important logic in child
    }, //other important methods
})
```